# .bat file to use a list of characters as a password

Tags: excel, batch-file, passwords, protected

I am looking for some help/guidance on creating a .bat file to pass a list of characters into a password dialog box in Excel.  In other words, I know that the password is 3 characters long (26^3 possibilities).  I tried using WorkSpace Macro Pro to do this, but it is taking too long.

My coworker recommended that I create a .bat file.  Where as I have 17,576 (26^3)lines of code. I would need a log file to see which password was successful in opening the file. I have never written a .bat file in my life, so maybe somebody can help me out!  Thanks!
Darren

Comment: may be this will help https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+password+recovery&oq=excel+passwor&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.7711j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into writing a VBA script to do that.  Are you trying to script inside of Excel, or are you trying to script to open the file?  If you trying to access something in the spreadsheet, you can write your own little macro programs to do all sorts of automation.  On Mac it's under `Tools | Macro | Macros...`

Comment: the problem is opening the file.  I put a password on the excel file.  So i need it just to open the file.  Mehul, I downloaded one of the applications, but it has an error on it.. sent that error to their help desk.  (i usually write down the passwords too)! ugh :)

Comment: Just a heads up, A LOT of those Excel password cracker programs are rittled with viruses/spyware/etc. 

Do you know how long the password is?  As pnuts pointed out, it might be more computationally intensive than you think.

Comment: That's why i'm scared about downloading a password cracker.. I scanned it with McAfee. Both on download and after install.  Not liking it.  I'm pretty sure it's all lower case and 3 letters.  I was just tinkering around the one day and was like i'll put a tiny pwd on it.  I usually always have a mixture of characters.  That's why I think this is doable.

Comment: Do you have to write a bat file?  Can you write a Java/C/Python program to do it?  It'd be fairly easy to do it in any of those.

Comment: I'm not a programmer.  I can write SQL and SAS.. but not java/C/python etc.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).  There are lots of people that know this kind of stuff over there.